# Running .NET 4.5 on Linux under .NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, containers

I am attempting to play around with porting/running an application written under .NET 4.5 on Linux.

First off I am by no means a .NET programmer. We have software developers where I work that handle this, but they are reluctant to even investigate the possibility of getting the code to run on Linux. Therefore I am attempting to see if I can at least get the application to compile and run in the hopes that it intrigues them to look at it further.

Therefore I installed the .NET core utilities on my machine and created a simple Hello World app (dotnet new). This was able to run under the .NET Core 1.0 framework (which to my understanding is .NET 5.0).

As our code is for .NET 4.5 I updated my project.json to the following

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Reflection": "4.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {}
  }
}
```

When I attempt to compile/run I get the following:

```
Project hwapp (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling hwapp for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1
/Users/ceronim/tmp/hwapp/project.json(10,16): error DOTNET1011: Framework not installed: .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1 in 

Compilation failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:00.0231976
```

So it is correctly trying to run under Framework 4.5.1 but errors with Framework not installed. This is where I am stuck, haven't been able to figure out how to get 4.5.1 framework installed. I figured having it set in the project.json would cause it to get downloaded and installed when running dotnet restore.

Any help would be appreciated.

** as an FYI I am running my tests inside a Docker container **

Comment: Shouldnt the target framework be netcore* ? I believe net* is for standard .Net

Comment: Framework netcore is for 5.0, but I am looking to run framework 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install and run .NET 4.5 on Linux.  (It only runs .NET Core, which was called 5.0 and now is called 1.0).

You need a Windows machine (or VM) to run 4.x.

Comment: Rick:Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.  I guess I got confused by the fact that you could set your framework (to net451) in project.json.

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.redhat.com/blog/author/donschenck/

Following this guide was very useful and actually explained my issue.

As Rick noted, 4.5 only runs on Windows. So you need to ensure that the code is compiled for .NET core 1.0.